# Should individual letters of the Latin alphabet be italicized?

Tags: italics

Dotting the i's and crossing the t's.

Dotting the *i*'s and crossing the *t*'s.

Should individual letters of the Latin alphabet be italicized in the above example?

EDIT (AFTER Neil Coffey's ANSWER): According to "The Chicago Manual of Style" (7.59) we should prefer the latter.

Comment: Er- whichever is clearer?

Comment: If the answer is in the Chicago Manual of Style, then shouldn't this question be closed as General Reference?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is so because, generally speaking, individual letters and combinations of letters of the Latin alphabet are usually italicized. So, my edit isn't the answer to my question. @RegDwightΒВBẞ8

Comment: @DavidWallace - Sure, the question will be closed as "Lewis Carroll's question".

Answer (score 4):

Neither holy scripture nor federal law dictates which to use.

If your publisher/editor etc has told you which to adopt, do whatever they have asked.

If your publisher/editor etc has told you to adhere to a particular style guide, do whatever that style recommends.

If nobody is compelling you to adopt either choice, which do you prefer?

Comment: Neither holy scripture nor federal law dictates which to use, but 'only' The Chicago Manual of Style (7.59)